# How to adjust version resolution in ivy

Tags: dependency-management, ivy

We are finding that ivy resolves some unexpected versions when we specify a version wildcard in ivy.xml.

For instance, when available versions are 6.2.RC, 6.2.11 , I would expect that "6.2.+" gives me "6.2.11". Unfortunately, I end up with "6.2.RC", which I assume is because alphabetically, "11" comes before "RC".

The same problem happens with "6.2.Final", which is a version number that some distros use to name their first minor release of a branch. It comes before "6.2.1", but is not interpreted as such by Ivy.

So, is there any way we can influence the resolution, so that "RC" and "Final" are considered "older" than "11"?